# Automatically writing headers using csv python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a motif finding function which takes amino acid fasta as an input and outputs an motifs in the excel file.

My desired output looks like this..

```
SeqName     M1      Hits    M2          Hits
Seq1        MN[A-Z] 3       V[A-Z]R[ML] 2
Seq2        MN[A-Z] 0       V[A-Z]R[ML] 5
Seq3        MN[A-Z] 1       V[A-Z]R[ML] 0
```

I've been trying to automatically generate the headers since the motifs that I'm searching for is over 2. (In the example above , there are only two(M1 and M2)).

The code that Ive been working on looks like this..

```
import re
from Bio import SeqIO
import csv
import collections

def SearchMotif(f1, motif, f2="motifs1.xls"):
    with open(f1, 'r') as fin, open(f2,'wb') as fout:
        writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter = '\t')

        writer.writerow(['M%s'%(i+1)for i in range(0,len(motif),1)])
        writer.writerow(['Hits' for i in range(0,len(motif),1)])
```

And this generates

```
M1      M2
Hits    Hits
```

Is there any way that I could make my header rows looks like my desired output?

Hits are static but M1 will be increased by length of motifs. So if I have 5 different types of motifs to search, it will be like..

```
SeqName    M1    Hits    M2    Hits    M3    Hits    M4    Hits    M5    Hits
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of what `motif` looks like and a what the desired output corresponding to that sample? It's hard to help if we don't know what the input looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple. make header row,

```
>>> headerrow = ['SeqName']
>>> for i in range(1,6):
...   headerrow.append('M%d' % i)
...   headerrow.append('Hits')
...
>>> headerrow
['SeqName', 'M1', 'Hits', 'M2', 'Hits', 'M3', 'Hits', 'M4', 'Hits', 'M5', 'Hits']
```

and write.

```
writer.writerow(headerrow)
```